# "От слова совсем/вообще" — неграмотно же?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Всюду в интернете попадается этот оборот. Мне он кажется неуклюжим и убогим. Это неграмотное выражение, верно?

Comment: Приведите примеры употребления, пожалуйста.

Comment: "У него нет денег, от слова вообще".

Comment: Так пишут? Бессмыслица полная.

Comment: Я с Вами полностью согласен. Но это стало попадаться мне так часто, что уже не пройти мимо. Звучит отвратительно.

Comment: @М_Г, "от слова совсем" не бессмыслица, это своего рода юмор. От частого повторения стирается, обесценивается – как и любой другой.

Comment: @Niemand, Для того, чтобы это звучало не как бессмыслица, а как юмор (пример : художник от слова худо) , следовало бы переделать эту  фразу как-то так (возможно, она так и звучала когда-то):  У него нет денег **совсем, от слова вообще**). Думаю, юмор не просто стерся, он исказился до полной глупости.

Comment: Нет, он вообще не изменился. Первоначально так и было: "Нет денег. От слова "совсем".

Answer (score 6):

> У него нет денег, от слова вообще.

Благодаря вопросу я познакомился с выражениями "от слова вообще", "от слова совсем" и  с удивлением обнаружил, что их употребляет сейчас всяк кому не лень, интернет "кишит" этими выражениями, но в половине случаев их цитируют возмущенные противники (по сути еще больше популяризируя то, против чего восстали). Откликнулась и Грамота:

> [Вопрос № 267995](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=267995)
> Замечаю, что в моду вошла фраза "от слова "совсем".
> Примеры употребления:
> У него нет таланта от слова "совсем".
> В отеле нет русскоязычных гидов от слова "совсем".
> Можно ли сказать, что это речевая избыточность? Допустимо ли использование этой фразы в литературной и разговорной речи?
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
> Скорее всего, это шутка, речевая игра. Такое возможно в разговорной речи.

Нашлась даже научная(?!) работа на эту тему:
Сергей Сергеевич Белоусов. [*От слова совсем* как грамматическая конструкция](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/ot-slova-sovsem-kak-grammaticheskaya-konstruktsiya)" (УЧЕНЫЕ ЗАПИСКИ ПЕТРОЗАВОДСКОГО ГОСУДАРСТВЕННОГО УНИВЕРСИТЕТА).

> В общем, призраки выражений "от слова вообще", "от слова совсем" бродят по интернету. Пора уже участникам этого сайта перед всем миром открыто изложить свое отношеное к указанной тенденции. (К.Маркс, Ф.Энгельс. Манифест Коммунистической партии)

По-моему, в большинстве случаев это звучит как полная бессмыслица. Для того, чтобы это звучало не как бессмыслица, а как юмор (по образцу "художник от слова худо"), следовало бы строить фразы, например, так: "У него нет денег **совсем, от слова вообще**". Возможно в самом начале оно так и было, а потом юмор не просто стерся, он исказился до полной глупости.

Вот несколько примеров, которые не вызывают отторжения:

> Никогда, от слова вообще...(https://oleni-xa.livejournal.com/1546403.html)
>
> Когда места нет совсем. От слова вообще. (https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5a53671b3dceb7851f1ecc9e/kogda-mesta-net-sovsem-ot-slova-voobsce-5aacee9e168a9112996a7b2a)

О деньгах я бы написал так: "У него нет денег, нет от слова вообще."

Comment: А почему в самом верхнем примере запятая?

Answer (score 2):

Сколько умных слов... Да, это обычная намеренная речевая ошибка, сделанная для привлечения внимания и усиления экспрессии и ушедшая в народ. Такой прием называется - эрратив. Пообносится, потеряет новизну, поблекнет и умрет.
Реклама Макдональдса "I'm loving it" - тоже содержит ошибку. Глагол to love - статичный. В continuous не употребляется.
Ошибка заставляет слушателя или читателя "споткнуться", остановиться, задуматься, перечитать или подольше покрутить звукообраз. Иногда даже проснуться. Проанализировать больше ассоциаций.
В разговорной речи, тем более экспрессивной, эрративы - норма. Если не эрративы, то мат. Для передачи экспрессии нужны инструменты. Сильных эпитетов всегда не хватает. А то будет - "Напрасно вы уронили мне кирпич на ногу..." Или - "Ваша неосторожность при перемещении кирпича привела к моим физическим страданиям".
Абсолютно все классики, на всех языках использовали эрративы. Конечно, гораздо более виртуозно, чем средний носитель языка.